# Is there an idiom for an event that something should be behind that?

Tags: idioms

I need to translate a Turkish idiom. Literal translation is "It is neither a festival nor a special day. So why did my brother-in-law kiss me?", which is used for unusual events seemingly without a causal relationship, but there is something behind it.

Comment: The expression 'high day or holiday', which obviously corresponds closely to your Turkish expression, used to be a lot more common in the UK than it is today. But most people would understand what you meant if you said 'It was neither a high day nor a holiday. So why did my brother-in-law kiss me?' Though they'd probably not identify with the custom.

Comment: so basically you want an idiom:  why did he kiss me?

Comment: I suspect it is a rhetorical question and not a request for an explanation. Like saying "is it my birthday" when a several good fortunes happen in quick succession. The OP might want to include an actual example of the situation where this would be used.

Comment: may we see the idiom and how you translated it to English?

Comment: Here it is: https://twitter.com/ahmetnesin_Eng/status/980184219329683456

Answer (score 1):

This idom may work: **no rhyme or reason** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+rhyme+nor+reason)

> A total absence of a reasonable or rational explanation for something.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's requirement 'which is used for unusual events seemingly without a causal relationship, but there is something behind it' but slinging in an 'apparently without' rectifies that. +1 in anticipation.